# Jumping to errors in EClipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

so when I compile a project in Visual Studio and it has errors, it shows them in a grid view and I can double click on its rows and it jumps to the line of error in the code. but now I am using EClipse for JavaEE and it is only showing errors in a text-based console editor and double clicking  does not jump to the line of error and I have to find it manually.
is there a handy way for doing this? or any free plug-in that is useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window -> show view -> problems